# Setting up url with parameter that can be consumed by web service

Tags: php, wordpress, restful-url

I am setting up a custom endpoint in the WordPress REST API that will call a SQL statement. I can not figure out how the url should be set up with the param that will need to be passed in and then how to get it out of the url so that it can be used in the SQL query.

I have tried to my url as the following:
https://www.mywebsitename.com/wp-json/prayerRequest/v1/1

The response I get back is:
{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}

The 1 at the end is the id that I need to pass in.

Here is my code:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'prayer_request_routes');

function prayer_request_routes() {  
    register_rest_route('prayerRequest/v1', '/{id}', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'getPrayerRequestById'
    ));
}

function getPrayerRequestById() {
    global $wpdb;
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_prayer_requests WHERE id = $id";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    return $result;
}
```

I want the $id variable to be that the id that come at the end the url.

Example:
The url https://www.mywebsitename.com/wp-json/prayerRequest/v1/1 would result in the SQL query SELECT * FROM wp_prayer_requests WHERE id = 1

Comment: have you tried the full url for the api? like base_url + 'prayerRequest/v1'

Comment: register_rest_route('https: //www.mywebsite.com/wp-json/prayerRequest/v1', '/{id}', array( 
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'getPrayerRequestById'
    ));

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the syntax to solve my problem.

The route:

```
register_rest_route( 'prayerRequest/v1', '/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'getPrayerRequestById'
));
```

The function:

```
function getPrayerRequestById(WP_REST_Request $request) {
    global $wpdb;
    $id = $param = urldecode($request->get_param( 'id' ));
    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_prayer_requests WHERE id = $id";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    return $result;
}
```